# How to find all "1" bits in a unsigned char bitmapRep[8192]?

Tags: c, algorithm, bitmap, bit

Given a unsigned char bitmapRep[8192], how to efficiently find out all "1" bits' positions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "find"?

This may seem like a smart-ass answer, but I'm perfectly serious:  you already *have* found them.  There's a perfect map describing exactly where all the 1 bits are found, and it has a bit set in the corresponding positions.

Answer (score 2):

Homework?

hint - Lookup table for each byte